# Does anyone know where I can define this URI parameter?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, web-parts

[image]

This happens when I try to deploy a Sharepoint WebPart solution. Is there a file or configuration option that I have missed that is causing this error to occur?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VSeWSS to deploy the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using VSeWSS 1.3 to deploy you solution and that these error occur when you try to deploy the solution. I'm not 100% sure but I think I had the same error some time ago. Unfortunately I could remember what I exactly did to solve this problem. But I'm quite sure the problem was related to some network issues as VSeWSS 1.3 uses web services to handle solutions.

So I would advise you to double check you network settings. For example you could try to adjust your hosts file so that your computer's name could be resolved.

Comment: Is there some configuration options for VSeWSS?

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like a configuration menu.

Comment: alright, thanks for the input. ill post back if i find something out.